# Cannot access Google Geocoding API response object

Tags: angularjs, resources, geocoding

my first message :)
well, i am trying to write a weather Spa with angular.
as part of the model ,  i need to grab the location Lat and Lon so im using google geocoding api.
after using `$resource.get` i am successfully getting the object from google but cant access it.
here is my code :

```
weatherApp.controller('forecastController'['$scope','location','$resource',function($scope,location,$resource){
    $scope.toGoogle = location.toGoogle;
    $scope.resource = $resource('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?');
    $scope.georesult = $scope.resource.get({address:$scope.toGoogle,Key:"somekey"})
   console.log(angular.fromJson($scope.georesult));
}]);
```

**$scope.toGoogle is just a var holding the address which needs to be translated into x and y**

the thing is - i am getting a response with the object i was expected, but when i am trying to access it with:

```
    console.log(angular.fromJson($scope.georesult.results[0].geometry.location.lat));
```

I am getting  **"TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"** 
(Please note that i have already transformed the Json into regular object with Angular.fromJson);

Any suggestions ? thanks in advance.

Comment: need to access it in promise callback. `$resource` is asynchronous

Comment: thanks man. can you give an example based on this use case ?

Comment: sure....docs for `$resource` have examples